# Cannot GET/ node.js server in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, websocket

When I am deploying the app in heroku and running, it gives `Cannot GET/` in the browser.

I cannot understand where exactly the problem is !

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

**client.js**

```
// When running in heroku
var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
var ws = new WebSocket(host);

// When running on local machine
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5000');
```

> **Local Folder Structure:**
>
> 1. .git
> 2. node_modules     // containing ws and express
> 3. client.js
> 4. index.html      // includes client.js
> 5. server.js
> 6. package.json

Comment: Does it work locally? Have you defined routes in express, or is this the only code in your app file?

Comment: @veggiesaurus It is working properly on local machine with the client.js as shown above ! + there is no other code for routing in express !

Comment: So the first block of code is your entire server.js?  Is it possible that your express server is running on port 80 in heroku, and your websocket client is trying to connect to port 80 as well?

Comment: My express server is running on port 5000 and any PaaS does not create these dependencies, so that may not be an issue ! But yes since in heroku I am not mentioning the port it may be a problem for websocket client to connect to the port on 5000 ! But I think this `Cannot GET /` is a route problem :(

Comment: @veggiesaurus I have seen from this heroku tutorial [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

Comment: I've copied your code and put it on heroku without any GET issues. I do run into websockets errors, but that's understandable. However, when I renamed "index.html" to "test.html", I encountered a GET error. I suspect that your "index.html" is not making it to your heroku server. Maybe you haven't added it to your repository?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83689/discussion-between-veggiesaurus-and-kaustav-ray).

Comment: Does you `package.json`  have a `start` script? If not, add `"start": "node server.js"` and try